# How to pass JSP parameters to a SQL query?

Tags: java, sql, jsp

I want to write a SQL query which contains parameters from a JSP.
I tried it like this

```
String sqlstring = "\"select"+Activity+" from backgroundcost where onpremprice =' "
                         +service+" '\"";
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sqlstring);
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

I'm getting an error.

Comment: Which error do you get?

Comment: MysqlsyntaxerrorException

Comment: Please update your question and add the StackTrace.

Comment: Try with something like `String sqlstring = "select " + Activity + " from backgroundcost where onpremprice = ?";` and `ps.setString(1, service);` (or `ps.setInt(1, service);` if it's a number)  instead.

Comment: @mick mnemonic that worked sir. Thank you!

Comment: But i m confused wat exctly happend! Can u please explain me this sir?

Comment: Basically, you had too many quotes in wrong places and were not using bind variables (and the `?` placeholder). Never concatenate variables into query literals, that's something you should keep in mind. Have a look at [the tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) for more info.

Comment: Thank you sir! I ll keep that in mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I hope you mean that `service` is a variable that comes from a form of your JSP, that this variable ends up in your Controller and that your controller delegates the access to the database layer to another class.

There are multiple problems with your request :

1. You use quotes inside your SQL query, you shouldn't.
2. What is `Activity` ? probably you miss a space character between ´select´ and the value of `Activity´
3. The goal of a ´PreparedStatement` is to avoid SQL Injection. You MUST use the code i show below instead of your parameter directly injected in your built SQL statement.
4. Consider using `StringBuilder`if you have multiple String concatenations

"

```
String sqlstring = "select activity from backgroundcost where onpremprice = ?";

PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sqlstring);
ps.setString(1, service);
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

Comment: Thank you sir for your detailed explaination. I got my mistakes and answer too. Thank you!

Comment: You welcome. You can select my answer as your valid answer then :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't is the short answer. It is a bad design to have database logic in your view. Pass the params from your jsp to a backend java bean en let that fill in the query

Answer (score 0):

make it like this..

```
  String sqlstring = "select * from backgroundcost where onpremprice ='"+service+" '";
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sqlstring);
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

// in place of * you can put the column name that u need to be selected.